# Javascript - Handling "The" When Sorting an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm asking this question to quality check myself and see if more experienced Javascript coders might have a better approach...

I have an array of titles, some of which begin with "The".  I don't want "The" to be taken into account when sorting the titles.  My planned approach is to use regex to cut "The" from the beginning of the value then splice it onto the end of the value before sorting the array.  For example, modify "The Right Stuff" to be "Right Stuff, The".

My question: is there a better/more efficient way of doing this than iterating through the array and making the regex modifications?

**EDIT**: Thanks to all who took the time to respond (and sorry for the delay).  I played around with both methods (regex cut and splice as well as comparison).  I ended up going the comparison route which fit best into the flow of my script.

Comment: use array.join and replace the "The" with empty character then split it in to arrays and sort it

Comment: are you really concerned about efficiency here? or are you looking for a clean and neat way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom comparison function which you can pass to your sorting algorithm which returns an appropriate value when it compares strings which have 'the' at the beginning and a string that doesn't. In all other cases, it could use the natural ordering. Once you have such a function, its a simple matter to sort the strings however you like them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort by the way.

Comment: The question was about a more efficient way to do it, which yours is certainly not.

Comment: Before making that comment, have you measured how long it actually takes?

Comment: @Hrishi the sorting function is applied ~N*log(N) times during sorting and it would have to exclude the "The" for both operands, so doing it your way wastes at least 2*log(N) times more time in excluding "The". Is that the best place to optimize the application? No idea, but the OP did ask for a more efficient way.

Comment: yes. But he also asked for a better way. I think passing in a custom sort function which he can potentially re-use if he needs it elsewhere is a much cleaner way of sorting than mucking with array's elements, using regexp to slice things off, constructing the original strings back and all that hackery.

Comment: If he really cared about efficiency, what he could potentially do is to have like a hidden value field which would be a number given for each string, based on his requirement and criteria (which I am not aware of) and sort on that while sorting the array and lo behold! he does not have to sort strings at all, it would be pure numeric sort.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just using `sort()` without any parameter.

If you have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You will notice that you can actually put in a custom function, in which you could skip the first 3 characters if they are "The" ( take in account the uppercase cases).

Your approach is valid also, as long as you do the reverse thing to output the titles properly later. In terms of performance, I haven't tested but unless you are working with huge arrays, it shouldn't be human-noticeable, so go on with whatever you feel it will be better to understand later / understandable for others.